# convert time to DataInterval instance

Tags: php

I'm attempting to convert interval to words.  I came across this error `Argument 1 passed to Database::intervalToWords() must be an instance of DateInterval, string given`.  How do i solve this, so i don't get an error?

```
//query from database

function one() {
            $posted = htmlspecialchars(strtotime($row['posted']),ENT_QUOTES);
                            $time_now = time(); //current date/time

                        $newposted = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',($time_now-$posted));

                        $newposted = $this->intervalToWords($newposted);

}





function intervalToWords(DateInterval $interval)
{
    $intervalStr = '';
    if ($interval->y > 0) {
    //if over a year
        $intervalStr = 'Over ' . $interval->y . ' year' . ($interval->y > 1 ? 's' : ''); //years or year
    } else {
        if ($interval->m > 2) {
        //if over 2 months
            $intervalStr = $interval->m . ' months';
        } else if ($interval->m > 0) {
            //if a month
            $intervalStr = $interval->m . ' month' . ($interval->m > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' and ' . $interval->d . ' day' . ($interval->d > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            if ($interval->d > 1) {
              //if over a day
                $intervalStr = $interval->d . ' days';
            } else if($interval->d == 1) {
              //if a day
                $intervalStr = '1 day, ' . $interval->h . ' hour' . ($interval->h > 1 ? 's' : '');
            } else {
                if ($interval->h > 0) {
                //if over an hour   
                    $intervalStr = $interval->h . ' hour' . ($interval->h > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ';
                }
                if ($interval->i > 0) {
                //if over a minute
                    $intervalStr .= $interval->i . ' minute' . ($interval->i > 1 ? 's' : '');
                } else {
                    $intervalStr = 'less than 1 minute';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $intervalStr . ' ago';
}
```

Comment: You've clearly copy/pasted this code from some tutorial without even reading it, if you're asking a question like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for: [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

But you need a baseline `DateTime` to diff from.

Comment: Yes, using [DateTime::setTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php).

Comment: i tried using diff and i get this error `Call to undefined method DateTime::diff`.. what does this mean?

Comment: You have to call `diff()` method of a `DateTime` instance, e.g. `$dateTimeICreatedSomehwere -> diff( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

And you probably forget to make instance of DateInterval Object:

```
//query from database    
function one() {
            $posted = htmlspecialchars(strtotime($row['posted']),ENT_QUOTES);
                            $time_now = time(); //current date/time

                        //$newposted = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',($time_now-$posted));
                        $dv = new DateInterval('PT'.($time_now-$posted).'S');

                        $newposted = $this->intervalToWords($dv);

}
```

Comment: If this works it's a more straight-forward solution than mine.